# Get a list of filenames without extension for all files in a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get all the files in a directory in a list.
Then I want to remove the extensions from the filenames.

This is the code I tried:

```
import os

myFiles = os.listdir()
print(myFiles)
sep = '.'
for myItem in myFiles:
   myItem = myItem.split(sep, 1)[0]
print(myFiles)
```

However the `myFiles` list is identical after the iteration, as with before the iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assigning a new value to `myItem` does not change the list `myFiles` even though `myItem` was originally a reference to an element of the list.

You either need to assign the new value to the position in the list,

```
import os

myFiles = os.listdir()
sep = '.'

for i, myItem in enumerate(myFiles):
    myFiles[i] = myItem.split(sep, 1)[0]
```

or create a new list. For example with a list comprehension:

```
import os

myFiles = os.listdir()
sep = '.'

myFiles = [myItem.split(sep, 1)[0] for myItem in myFiles]
```

By the way, there is a function in the standard library to split the extension from the filename:

```
>>> from os.path import splitext
>>> splitext('hello.txt')
('hello', '.txt')
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext